# Broken theme, stylesheet is missing after uploading the right theme via FTP

Tags: themes, css, ftp

I have purchased a third party theme via themeforest and have downloaded the zip file, unzipped it and uploaded the flies via Filezilla on to the server. When I refresh WordPress and head back to Appearance/Themes, I can see the below:

[image]

I have double checked all the files within the theme directory in Filezilla and I can see 2 css files in there:

1. style-rtl.css
2. style.css

Does anyone know why I am still getting that error even though both css have been successfully upload via ftp on to the server?
Thank you,

Comment: Did you try uploading the zipped theme via WP install theme as well? Make sure you downloaded the installable zip from themeforest- sometimes they provide zips with docs etc too - not meant to be installed

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations; downloading all files and documentation and from within there, selecting the them.zip file; downoading installable wordpress file only; have tried moving the files within the server and sticking them to the wpcontent root...I have ran out of ideas!

Comment: @Jose, are you 100% certain the stylesheet file at `wp-content/themes/aardvark-theme/style.css` exists? Do you use any caching plugins?

Comment: hey apologies for the late reply and thank you for your input. all sorted now!